# Run a salt script job that never returns to the salt master

Tags: java, command-line, salt-stack

I have a salt SLS file, test.sls as follows,

```
test:
  cmd.run:
   - name : |
       java -jar test.jar
```

Here test.jar runs a command which is to launch eclipse and run a specified configuration(which runs forever). Since this runs forever(unless I stop) when I run the following command,

```
sudo salt 'ubuntu' state.sls test
```

This will not return to the master from minion. What will happen in this case? will the job automatically stopped after certain time out? In general how to run jobs that never end using salt?

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution!
If you redirect the `stdout`/`stderr` to `/dev/null`, it is possible to run the process in background and prevent `salt` from waiting for the process.
Here is an example:

```
run-my-cmd:
   cmd.run:
      - name: ./run-your-script >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

If your script has some `stdout`, you should ensure:

> Many state functions in this module now also accept a stateful
>   argument. If stateful is specified to be true then it is assumed that
>   the command or script will determine its own state and communicate it
>   back by following a simple protocol

And your end of the output should be:

```
# writing the state line 
echo  # an empty line here so the next line will be the last. 
echo "changed=yes comment='something has changed' whatever=123"
```

Check [`salt.states.cmd`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html).

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using:

```
test:
  cmd.run:
   - name : |
       sh -c "java -jar test.jar >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

I din't try it but it should put the process you want in background while the main sh command quits.

Comment: This does not work! I am trying to do this but the salt command hangs indefinitely. Tried in debug mode running a job on the minion (using `salt-call`) as well as from the master (using `salt`).